# Accessing OS X kill ring programmatically

Tags: macos, clipboard, pasteboard, kill-ring

I recently noticed, that OS X has another clipboard which you can access by killing something with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then yanking it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.

I know I can access OS Xs normal clipboard with `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`. Sadly you cannot access the kill ring like that. Is there some other way?
I don't care if it is by Cocoa, some weird Core C library or by some terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I see no evidence that that kill ring is ever exposed to other processes. If you kill something in one app and try to yank it in another, it doesn't work. In fact, the two apps maintain their separate kill rings no matter what you do in the other.

So, I very much doubt it's accessible externally.